# Interesting integral 5

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

Find an integral:
$$
\int\limits_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^3 \ln^2 x}{1+x^7} d x.
$$
Should I use residue theorem? May somebody suggest any ideas to find it?

Comment: Try making you contour look like a C, then apply the residue theorem. That might work

Comment: Kinda like this http://www.uprh.edu/rbaretti/Branch1.jpg

Comment: Use Euler Beta  function or write $\int_0^{\infty}=\int_0^{1}+\int_1^{\infty}$ and perform the change of variable $y=1/x$ in the last integral.

Comment: The residues calculations will be cumbersome. You can also differentiate the beta function twice.

Answer (score 1):

We do this in three steps, using  a pizza slice contour resting on the
positive real axis and of radius $R$ with the angle being $2\pi/7.$ We
start with

$$J_0 = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{1+x^7} dx.$$

We get  $J_0$ on  the real  axis.  The  circular arc  is of  the order
$(2\pi/7)  \times  R  \times   \frac{R^3}{R^7}$  and  hence  makes  no
contribution.   We get  on  the upper  part  parameterizing with  $z=x
\exp(2\pi i/7)$ a  multiplier of $\exp(6\pi i/7)  \exp(2\pi i/7).$ The
only pole inside the slice is the one at $\rho = \exp(\pi i/7)$ and we
get for the residue

$$\frac{\rho^3}{7\rho^6} = -\frac{\rho^4}{7}.$$

Hence by the Cauchy Residue Theorem we find that

$$J_0 (1-\exp(8\pi i/7)) = - 2\pi i \frac{\rho^4}{7}$$

so that

$$J_0 = - 2\pi i \frac{1}{7} \frac{\exp(4\pi i/7)}{1-\exp(8\pi i/7)}
= - 2\pi i \frac{1}{7} \frac{1}{\exp(-4\pi i/7)-\exp(4\pi i/7)}
\\ = \frac{1}{7} \frac{\pi}{\sin(4\pi/7)}.$$

Next we continue with

$$J_1 = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3 \log x}{1+x^7} dx$$

where we indent the pizza slice  around the origin. The large circular
arc makes no contribution in the  limit, same as before. The small arc
is  dominated by  $2\pi \epsilon/7  \times \epsilon^3  |\log\epsilon +
2\pi i|$ which vanishes as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0.$

We  get from the upper part of the slice

$$- J_0 \exp(8\pi i/7) \times 2\pi i/7
- J_1 \exp(8\pi i/7).$$

The residue now becomes

$$-\frac{\exp(4\pi i/7)}{7} (\pi i/7)$$

We thus have

$$J_1 (1-\exp(8\pi i/7)) = J_0 \exp(8\pi i/7) \times 2\pi i/7 
- 2\pi i \frac{\exp(4\pi i/7)}{7} (\pi i/7).$$

This yields

$$J_1 = J_0 \frac{\exp(8\pi i/7)}{1-\exp(8\pi i/7)} \times 2\pi i/7
+ J_0 \frac{\pi i}{7}
\\ = J_0 \frac{\pi i}{7} \frac{1+\exp(8\pi i/7)}{1-\exp(8\pi i/7)}
= - J_0 \frac{\pi i}{7} \frac{2\cos(4\pi/7)}{2i\sin(4\pi/7)}
= - J_0 \frac{\pi}{7} \cot(4\pi /7)
\\ = - \frac{\pi^2}{7^2} \frac{\cot(4\pi /7)}{\sin(4\pi/7)}.$$

To conclude we treat the target integral which is

$$J_2 = \int_0^\infty \frac{x^3 \log^2 x}{1+x^7} dx.$$

We  use $(\log  x  + 2\pi  i/7)^2  = \log^2  x  + 4\pi  i/7  \log x  -
4\pi^2/7^2$ and obtain on the upper part (same contour, same estimates
on the arcs)

$$J_0 \exp(8\pi i/7) \frac{4\pi^2}{7^2}
- J_1  \exp(8\pi i/7) \frac{4\pi i}{7} - J_2  \exp(8\pi i/7)$$

so that

$$J_2 = J_0 \frac{\exp(8\pi i/7)}{1-\exp(8\pi i/7)}
\left(-\frac{4\pi^2}{7^2} - \frac{4\pi^2 i}{7^2}\cot(4\pi/7)\right)
- J_0 \frac{\pi^2}{7^2}
\\ =  -\frac{4\pi^2}{7^2} J_0 \frac{\exp(8\pi i/7)}{1-\exp(8\pi i/7)}
(1+i\cot(4\pi/7)) - J_0 \frac{\pi^2}{7^2}.$$

To simplify this  we momentarily put $z = \exp(4\pi  i/7)$ and get for
the central term

$$\frac{z^2}{1-z^2} \left(1+i\frac{(z+1/z)/2}{(z-1/z)/2/i}\right)
= \frac{z^2}{1-z^2} \left(1- \frac{z+1/z}{z-1/z}\right)
\\ = -\frac{z^2}{1-z^2} \frac{2/z}{z-1/z}
= -\frac{z^2}{1-z^2} \frac{2}{z^2-1} = \frac{2z^2}{(z^2-1)^2}
= \frac{2}{(z-1/z)^2}.$$

Putting it all together we obtain

$$-\frac{\pi^3}{7^3} \frac{1}{\sin(4\pi/7)}
\left(4 \times -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sin^2(4\pi/7)} + 1\right)
\\ = \frac{\pi^3}{7^3} \frac{1}{\sin(4\pi/7)}
\left(\frac{2}{\sin^2(4\pi/7)} - 1\right)
= \frac{\pi^3}{7^3} \frac{2-\sin^2(4\pi/7)}{\sin^3(4\pi/7)}.$$

We conclude that the integral is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{\pi^3}{7^3} \frac{1+\cos^2(4\pi/7)}{\sin^3(4\pi/7)}.}$$

Comment: Awesomee  (+1) .

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{equation}
\mbox{Note that}\quad
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{3}\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{7}}\,\dd x =
\left.\partiald[2]{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\mu} \over 1 + x^{7}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 3}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

---

With $\ds{x \equiv \pars{{1 \over t} - 1}^{1/7} \implies
t = {1 \over 1 + x^{7}}}$:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{\mu} \over 1 + x^{7}}\,\dd x & =
\int_{1}^{0}t\pars{{1 \over t} - 1}^{\mu/7}
\bracks{{1 \over 7}\pars{{1 \over t} - 1}^{-6/7}\pars{-\,{1 \over t^{2}}}}\dd t
\\[6mm] & =
{1 \over 7}\int_{0}^{1}t^{-\pars{\mu + 1}/7}\pars{1 - y}^{\pars{\mu - 6}/7}
\,\dd t =
{1 \over 7}\,{\Gamma\pars{\bracks{6 - \mu}/7}\Gamma\pars{\bracks{\mu + 1}/7} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 7}\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi\bracks{\mu + 1}/7}} =
{1 \over 7}\,\pi\csc\pars{{\pi \over 7}\,\bracks{\mu + 1}}
\end{align}

> After a 'laborious' procedure; I'll find, by replacing in \eqref{1},

$$\bbx{\ds{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{3}\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{7}}\,\dd x =
{\pi^{3} \over 686}\bracks{3 - \cos\pars{\pi \over 7}}
\sec^{3}\pars{\pi \over 14}}} \approx 0.1024
$$